# "firebase serve" not talking to a local instance.

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am using "firebase serve" to debug my Firebase web app locally. I found it doesn't connect to my local Firebase Functions. After I run "firebase serve", it says:

> ✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000

But the backend is still points to the remote version. For example, if I make a un-deployed local change, it won't show up. Also, I am not seeing any backend loggings.

Comment: Yes, that's currently a known limitation.

Comment: I'm trying to get the same thing going. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#serve_and_test_your_firebase_project_locally) explicitly says: "...emulate your project using local HTTP functions. To emulate HTTP functions and hosting for testing on local URLs, use either of the following commands:"

Comment: @DougStevenson Also [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator): "If you’re using Cloud Functions to generate dynamic content for Firebase Hosting, firebase serve, by default, uses your local HTTP functions as proxies for hosting."